# How to login in one of my Angular frontend applications and then navigate to other frontend applications without again asking for authentication

Tags: asp.net, angular, authentication, oauth-2.0, frontend

We have a single database and single API with .net (using OAuth2) and we have multiple angular applications. I need to login once on any of angular applications and navigate to other applications without asking for login again

Comment: I suggest you look into JWT authentication and use the same keystore to validate your JWT tokens between those multiple applications

Comment: if they're in the same domain, simply store your token in the localStorage and it will be accessible from any app withing that domain, so check for its existence on boot and you're good to go

Comment: i'm agree with @RDNotorious, when you navigate to other applications you should send a request to your backend to check if your token is still validate

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend thinking about the security and scoping aspects first, and start with the standard behaviour:

**STANDARD BEHAVIOUR**

Each app does an OAuth redirect and gets its own tokens:

- For app 1 the user has to log in
- For app 2 sign in is automatic / SSO

If an attacker steals an app 1 token, they cannot use it to access app 2 resources. This architecture is simple and scales well as you add more apps.

**INTEGRATED WEB PLATFORM BEHAVIOUR**

If you are aiming for this behaviour, it is also possible with OAuth, and tends to involve a domain wide cookie that spans all apps:

- User signs in to mail.google.com
- User navigates to drive.google.com without any redirects

I discuss this option further at the bottom of [this blog post](https://authguidance.com/2020/07/21/spa-reverse-proxy-based-token-renewal/), but it could result in quite a few technical conflicts over time.